# print message in lower tk frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, coinbase-api

the information I want to show in my lower tk frame appears in the idle shell when I click the button. Im hoping someone can tell me how to fix that?  (I deleted my api details from this)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
import json

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
total = 0
message = []
accounts = client.get_accounts()
for wallet in accounts.data:
    message.append( str(wallet['name']) + ' ' +   str(wallet['native_balance']) )
    value = str( wallet['native_balance']).replace('USD','')
    total += float(value)
message.append( 'Total Balance: ' + 'USD ' + str(total) )

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = Canvas(width = 444, height = 444, bg = 'gray24')
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "/Users/dusty/Pictures/Background.jpg")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = image, anchor = NW)

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='gray24', bd=5)
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')


button = tk.Button(frame, text="go", font=40, command=lambda: print('\n'.join( message )))
button.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)
entry = tk.Entry(frame, font=40)
entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=1)
lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='gray24', bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.5, anchor='n')


mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

this will do what you wanted, however it uses pysimplegui instead of tkinter

```
import time
import cbpro
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import PySimpleGUI as sg

auth_client = cbpro.AuthenticatedClient('780adsfasdfasdfbf45ff0aasdfasdf08fasdfa1',
'ahahEgasd9OLTD5Tasdfasdfasdf/asdfasdf/asdf/asdf/adfQ9mJtRRyRDG961hadsfasdfNsg==',
'0aadsjhfasdfasdn4rk')

fiat = 'USD'
coin = 'XTZ'
currency = 'XTZ-USD'


#get account id for chosen pair
def account(iD):
 for account in auth_client.get_accounts():
  if account['currency'] == iD:
   return account['id']


sg.theme('Black')

layout = [[sg.Text(currency,size=(40,20),key='-OUTPUT-')],[sg.Button('Run'),sg.Button('Quit')]]

window = sg.Window('Ellie | Algorithmic Trader', layout, alpha_channel=.9, grab_anywhere=True)



while True: # Event Loop

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'Quit':
      window.close()
      break

    if event == 'Run':
      
        def update():
          price = float(auth_client.get_product_ticker(product_id=currency)['price']) 
          window['-OUTPUT-'].update(price)

        update()

window.close()
```